# play framework not deployed to heroku

Tags: heroku, playframework-2.1

I'm following through [this tutorial](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/JavaTodoList) when finally deploying to Heroku via `git push heroku master`, and visiting the webpage, it fails with an `Application Error`. `heroku logs` has the following:

```
2013-12-18T18:27:30.109623+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `target/start -Dhttp.port=${PORT} -DapplyEvolutions.default=true -Ddb.default.url=${DATABASE_URL} -Ddb.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver`
2013-12-18T18:27:31.051319+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: target/start: No such file or directory
```

Indeed, there's no target/start file at all. How do I fix this?

Comment: `target/start` should appear as a result of `-----> Running: sbt clean compile stage`, make sure you see this line after the push.

Comment: Hi, Andrey, the compile goes well

Comment: Unfortunately I can't paste the output due to stackoverflow's limitations, but the line you mentioned is one of the first, and all goes well.        [success] Total time: 4 s, completed Dec 19, 2013 10:43:18 AM
-----> Dropping ivy cache from the slug
-----> Dropping project boot dir from the slug
-----> Dropping compilation artifacts from the slug
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web

-----> Compressing... done, 84.3MB
-----> Launching... done, v6
       http://rocky-stream-1895.herokuapp.com deployed to Heroku

Comment: Here's my app with App Error: http://rocky-stream-1895.herokuapp.com/

Comment: heroku logs: 2013-12-19T10:43:33+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2013-12-19T10:43:40.057039+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `target/start -Dhttp.port=${PORT} -DapplyEvolutions.default=true -Ddb.default.url=${DATABASE_URL} -Ddb.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver`
2013-12-19T10:43:40.850702+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `target/start -Dhttp.port=${PORT} -DapplyEvolutions.default=true -Ddb.default.url=${DATABASE_URL} -Ddb.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver`

Comment: 2013-12-19T10:43:40.980722+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: target/start: No such file or directory
2013-12-19T10:43:41.955279+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: target/start: No such file or directory
2013-12-19T10:43:42.398348+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-12-19T10:43:43.481126+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

Answer (score 0):

Change Procfile to:

```
web: target/universal/stage/bin/play ...
```

The location of play has changed